# Select Min value row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, min

I want to select the whole `row` which has a `min price`. Because I need some more column's data to display which has minimum price. Something like below.

```
 SELECT ep.*, min(ep.price) minprice FROM Equip_price ep;
```

How can I get done with Oracle DB?

---

### Update

I actually want to get the equipment_price by equipment_id. 
Below is a sample data.

```
  pid   equipmentID     price
  1        1              50
  2        2              20
  3        1             100
  4        1              20
  5        3             100
  6        3              10
  7        1              20
```

and I want the result like. ( min price group by equipmentID)

```
 id   equipmentID     price
  4        1              20
  2        2              20     
  6        3              10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Specific answer :

```
SQL> WITH Equip_price AS
  2    ( SELECT 1 pid, 1 equipmentID, 50 price FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 2 , 2 , 20 FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 3 , 1 , 100 FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 4 , 1 , 20 FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 5 , 3 , 100 FROM dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 6 , 3 , 10 FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT 7 , 1 , 20 FROM dual
 15    )
 16  SELECT ep.pid,
 17         ep.equipmentID,
 18         ep.price
 19   FROM (
 20         SELECT ep.*,
 21                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ep.equipmentID ORDER BY ep.price)
 22                  AS row_identifier
 23         FROM Equip_price ep
 24        ) ep
 25   WHERE ep.row_identifier = 1;

       PID EQUIPMENTID      PRICE
---------- ----------- ----------
         4           1         20
         2           2         20
         6           3         10

SQL>
```

For example, to get the employee details with minimum salary in each department -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT deptno, MIN(sal) min_sal FROM emp GROUP BY deptno
  3    )
  4  SELECT * FROM emp A, DATA b
  5  WHERE A.deptno = b.deptno
  6  AND A.sal = b.min_sal
  7  /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO     DEPTNO    MIN_SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20         20     800
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30         30     950
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10         10       1300
```

You could also use Analytic function like **ROW_NUMBER**.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY sal) rn FROM emp t
  3    )
  4  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno =
  5    (SELECT empno FROM data WHERE rn = 1
  6    )
  7  /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20

SQL>
```

---

**Without CTE :**

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM Equip_price E
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT ep.equipmentID, min(ep.price) minprice
               FROM Equip_price ep
              GROUP BY ep.equipmentID
            ) aggr
ON (E.equipmentID = aggr.equipmentID AND E.price = aggr.minprice)
```

OR

```
SELECT ep.id,
       ep.equipmentID,
       ep.price
 FROM (
       SELECT ep.*,
              row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ep.equipmentID ORDER BY ep.price)
                AS row_identifier
       FROM Equip_price ep
      ) ep
 WHERE ep.row_identifier = 1;
```

Comment: I think first solution can't work Because I have duplicate  `sal ` details.

Comment: Exactly, as I said you need to be sure if sub-query returns more than single row. Go for second solution. Or use `IN`.

Comment: Pls give example how to use `IN`   here.

Comment: `WHERE sal in (SELECT MIN(sal) FROM emp)`

Comment: sorry, I want to modify my sql. Actually I want the `min` price `group by equipid`. in your example say `min` sal `group by dept_id`. please help to find the min value with group by some value

Comment: @Mahesh, thanks indeed. Sometimes CTE confuses newbies.

Comment: Sorry Lalit Still I get duplicate. Actually my table, I updated. It now has `pid` `7` with similar `price`. so if I use your first query I get duplicate records for `equipmentID`

Comment: @everalian, please see the update on top. It has your complete answer. The WITH clause is just to build your table, don't be confused, focus on the query. Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(x.pid) as min_pid, x.equipmentID, y.min_price
from Equip_price x
inner join
(
    select equipmentID, min(price) as min_price
    from Equip_price
    group by equipmentID
) y on y.equipmentID = x.equipmentID and y.min_price = x.price
group by x.equipmentID, y.min_price
order by 2;
```